# In ui-router links to the same state with different params don't do anything

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a menu that has several links that all use the same ui-router state.

They all have different params and different URL's as a result.

All of these links work when clicked while on a different state.

Once you click one and enter the "range" state however none of the links now function.

**The HTML:**

```
<a ui-sref="range({type: 'foo'})" class="dropdown-item text">
    Product Foo
</a>
<a ui-sref="range({type: 'bar'})" class="dropdown-item text">
    Product Bar
</a>
```

**The state definition:**

```
var _range = [ 'foo', 'bar' ];

  module.config([ '$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {
    var rangeState = {
      parent: 'layout',
      url: '/{type:' + _range.join('|') + '}-doors',
      data: {
        range: _range
      },
      views: {
        'main@': {
          templateUrl: 'doors/range/range.html',
          controller: 'rangeController'
        }
      },
      resolve: {
        range: [ '$stateParams', 'rangeResource', function($stateParams, rangeResource) {
          return rangeResource.query({ range: $stateParams.type }).then(function(range) {
            range.name = $stateParams.type;
            return range;
          });
        }]
      }
    };

    $stateProvider.state('range', rangeState);
  }]);
```

Can anyone help me figure out while this isn't working?

To see this in action go to https://uat.yaledoor.co.uk and from the "Door Styles" dropdown menu select a link on the left.  The first time it will take you to the page.  Subsequent clicks to other links in the same dropdown will fail to do anything.

Comment: hard to tell what the problem is. I would try to remove the router config step by step until its working. May I would try to remove the param in the url first and try it with static urls to see if I can isolate the error.

Comment: It turns out that it was nothing to do with ui-router but rather there is another script injected into the page by AppDynamics that was causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your state will work on reload option if you are using same state with different param.

Try this:

```
$stateProvider.state('range', rangeState, {reload: true});
```

Comment: that's a valid workaround if it's working. But in my opinion it should reload the state if the param changes even without reload: true

Comment: in your case it would be a: `ui-sref="range({type: 'foo'})" ui-sref-opts="{reload: true}"`

Comment: I have tried the `ui-sref-opts="{reload: true}"` with no effect.  I've also tried changing the ui-sref's to ng-click using $state.go both with and without the reload option.

Comment: Then it may have something to do with your controller or service code.

Comment: No. Turns out it was AppDynamics injecting javascript into the page that was causing the issue.  Working with them on it.

Answer (score 0):

Your URL for the state looks suspect.  Generally you define them with specific matches in the following manner:

```
URL: "/{type:foo|bar}"
```

In your case, it looks like you're trying to append "-doors" to the type such that you get URLs like "#/foo-doors" or "#/bar-doors".  So you'll need to append that to your values in `ranges` before you pass them to the URL matching string.

Comment: I do have them defined in the live code exactly as you suggest.  The example code I posted is a bare minimum needed to replicate the issue.   The actual code looks like this `url: '/{type:' + _range.join('|') + '}-doors',` the output of which would be as per your example.

Comment: The problem in what you have is that the `-doors` falls outside of the *regexp• that the URL matcher uses.   It needs to fall within the `{  }` in order to qualify as part of the segment.  That's why I was saying you have to append the `-doors` to each of the types in order for it to process within that regexp segment.  BTW, I am using regexp loosely as it is a specific subset of regexp that UiRouter processes.

Comment: No, the -doors is outside and ui-router correctly picks up the parameter without the -doors on it.  Turns out it was AppDynamics injecting javascript into the page that was causing the issue.  Working with them on it.